# Prevent packages 'on hold' to show up when I upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management

I did `sudo apt-mark hold nameofthepackage` on 3 packages, but now I have an annoying remark when I upgrade with `sudo apt-get upgrade` :

```
Following packages have been holded : 
  package1 package2 package3
0 upgraded, 0 installed, 0 to remove and 3 non-updated.
```

(I'm sorry about the unexact output of the terminal, I'm using a french-version and I don't know exactly how to say this in english.)

Does it exist a way of "hiding" this ? I would like to have the usual `0 non-updated` even when I hold packages. Thanks

Comment: it's absolutely NOT a duplicate of that... I'm looking for a way to hold a package without displaying it's on hold.

Comment: I apologies for misunderstanding your question Sir.

Comment: No need for old workaround (deleted), as there is a better one.

Comment: try `LC_ALL=C sudo apt-get upgrade` to get the output in english

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Pin a package version using Apt Preferences

1. Check current priority policy for my package, Example with `virtualbox`:

   ```
   $ apt-cache policy virtualbox
   virtualbox:
     Installed: 4.3.6-dfsg-1
     Candidate: 4.3.6-dfsg-2
     Version table:
        4.3.6-dfsg-2 0
           500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
    *** 4.3.6-dfsg-1 0
           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```
2. Create new file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/apt/preferences.d/my_pin
   ```
3. Add package you want (joker `*` can be used), with higher priority (default `0`, max `1000`, or even negative value like `-1` to skip a version)

   ```
   Package: virtualbox*
   Pin: version 4.3.6-dfsg-1
   Pin-Priority: 500
   ```
4. Check again:

   ```
   $ apt-cache policy virtualbox
   virtualbox:
     Installed: 4.3.6-dfsg-1
     Candidate: 4.3.6-dfsg-1
     Package pin: 4.3.6-dfsg-1
     Version table:
        4.3.6-dfsg-2 500
           500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
    *** 4.3.6-dfsg-1 500
           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```
5. No need to use hold, So `sudo apt-mark unhold virtualbox` but you could leave it as 2nd lock.

Now, if I check `apt-get update`, nothing is mentioned about about `virtualbox` (In held back packages listing).

- Reference: [How to use APT Preferences Pinnig](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences)
- Hash sign `#` can be used to comment lines in APT Preferences files.