# How do I hold package regardless of revision change?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I have a local repository.

Yesterday I knew that `apt-get` downloads a package even if that  is only a repackage of the same content with revision change. Many package-maintainers do this for newer release versions.

**Example Scenario:**

I have an icon theme `malys-uniblue` which has version `1.7~saucy~NoobsLab.com` and a newer version was in repository with version `1.7~trusty~Noobslab.com`. I extract both of them and realized that it is only a repackaging. Since, icon themes are heavy on size, I don't want to download this newer repackaged deb file with only revision changes.

As, We see that only revision is changed i.e `~saucy` to `~trusty` and major part of version remained same.

The question is - Is it possible to ignore updates of packages with these kind of revision changes or repackagings? I know I need to create some preference file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d` to give higher priority to local repo ignoring revisions. How do I do this?

TL;DR

What I want is if apt see an update with a revision change that requires download, it'll ignore it and prefer the local repo version.

Comment: Isnt't this working? http://askubuntu.com/questions/556101/how-to-prevent-unnecessary-updates/556149#556149 I am afraid `apt-get` does not  see if an update is substantial or not.

Comment: Yes, `apt-get` doesn't see. But, I can hold a package's specific version by using apt-pinning. Only want to know whether that works for revisions too!

Comment: Ah, I understand.

Comment: @Anwar ,yes it works for full version string. `1.7~saucy~NoobsLab.com` just confirm that is same declared in the `debian/control` file too. Here an eexample that i had tried before https://askubuntu.com/questions/414216/prevent-packages-on-hold-to-show-up-when-i-upgrade/422051

Comment: @user.dz I think I wasn't very clear on it. I don't want to hold manually each package. I want to ignore those minor revisions. I know holding works.

Comment: @user.dz I edited the question. See if that makes more sense. What I want is if apt see an update with a revision change that requires download, it'll ignore it and prefer the local repo version.

Comment: @Anwar, it seems clear now to me. I will give a try to some currently in mind and back to you.